# .net cannot read pem file after publish to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, pem

I have an MVC Web Application which reads a .pem file for encyption. In IIS Express, I copied the .pem file on IIS Express folder, and I could get it like

```
RSA rsa = RSA.FromPublicKey(BIO.File("./RSAKeys/TestPublic.pem", "r"));
```

When I publish the project on IIS the code above gives me the errors:

error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process
error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file

I copied the RSAKeys folder both on the bin folder and the root folder of the project.

I could not get over this error. What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the corresponding physical directory on the server.

```
RSA rsa = RSA.FromPublicKey(BIO.File(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/RSAKeys/TestPublic.pem"), "r"));
```